# Update multiple rows using math to add to existing value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to update multiple rows. Some rows may have a value already. So if the value in that row was 2 and I wanted to update it with an additional 4 to make total of 6. How can I do that without querying each row for it's current value? Or must I do that?

I currently have something like thing like this.

```
item_match = Item.where("id IN (?)", item_match_ids).to_a
item_match.update_all(quantity: quantity)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you must remove the `to_a`, leaving this way:

```
Item.where(id: [id1, id2, ...]).update_all(quantity: quantity)
```

But, if you want to add a quantity to each record you need use find each:

```
Item.where(id: [id1, id2, ...]).find_each do |item|
  item.update(quantity: item.quantity + quantity)
end
```

You will find more of `find_each` [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each)

Answer (score 4):

If adding the same value to all records, you can use the following:

```
item_match.update_all("quantity = quantity + #{ quantity }")
```

This is much faster than updating the records individually. To be safe, you should make the `quantity` column non-null and set a default value. Be sure to sanitize the `quantity` value for SQL if it's user-supplied.